# Nasm x86 Check for UNDERflow

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

Considering a 16 bits architecture:

In the following code,

test.s

```
bits 16

section .text


test:
    aam 7       ; divide n by 7
    mov cl, al  ; cl = n % 7
    dec ecx     ; <--- here if n was power of 7 we get the underflow

    ; ... more things where I make use of ah = n / 7

    add eax, ecx ; return that number
    ret
```

I would like to know how could I check for the **under**flow. both `jo`, `adc` and `setc` (ok normal for the carry flag) are of no use.

If it is not possible then assembly code that converts ecx to 0 only if it is negative

Comment: `dec ecx` sets SF if it produces a negative result; (from decrementing the old garbage in ECX with a new low byte merged in...) You can use that with `cmovs` or `js`.  (Or `cmovl` / `jl`).

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter,  ```js``` did the trick. You might want to answer

Comment: As I commented on your code golf link, `dec ecx` sets SF according to the whole ECX register, but `mov cl, al` only merges a new low byte into whatever existing bytes were there.  Also, "multiple of 7", not "power", for remainder = 0.

Comment: I will recompile the file in local to make sure about the bytecodes and review your suggestions and make the edits accordingly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it thanks to @PeterCordes, helped me to coin my answer for [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/206543/how-many-weekdays/219094#219094) :

```
0:  d4 07                   aam    0x7          ; eax contains n, with aam 0x7 -> al = n % 7 and ah = n / 7 
2:  88 c1                   mov    cl,al        ; keep result of n%7 in ecx
4:  66 c1 e8 08             shr    ax,0x8       ; by shifting 8 times ax, ax=al=n/7;
8:  66 6b c0 05             imul   ax,ax,0x5    ; we multiply by 5
c:  49                      dec    ecx          ; ecx = ecx - 1 -> give 65535 if n was power of 7
d:  78 02                   js     11 <end>     ; if it happened we don't care about the remainder so we can just return n/7*5, the Signed Flag will be set so we can jump 2 bytes forward.
f:  01 c8                   add    eax,ecx      ; if not then we add (n%7)-1 to n/7*5
00000011 <end>:
11: c3                      ret
```